# qtips2 results in a blank screen rather than tooltips being shown in IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tooltip, qtip2

I have a MVC application that makes extensive use of [qtips2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) for showing bubble tooltips. The content that is being shown includes `Cufon` fonts. The tooltips are showing perfectly in `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Safari`, but in `IE 9` when I hover over the text that should popup the tooltip instead of the tooltip being shown the whole screen goes white. If I right click on the blank screen and go to source, then instead of the page content I see the following:

```
<style type="text/css">cufoncanvas{text-indent:0!important;}@media screen{cvml\:shape,cvml\:rect,cvml\:fill,cvml\:shadow{behavior:url(#default#VML)!important;display:block!important;antialias:true!important;position:absolute!important;}cufoncanvas{position:absolute!important;text-align:left!important;}cufon{display:inline-block!important;position:relative!important;vertical-align:text-bottom!important;}cufon cufontext{position:absolute!important;left:-10000in!important;font-size:1px!important;}a cufon{cursor:pointer}}@media print{cufon cufoncanvas{display:none!important;}}</style>
```

This style tag is *the only* thing that is shown in the source.

Here is an example of a tooltip in the source:

```
<mark data-url="../Tooltips/Tourism">tourism</mark>
```

And the source for initializing the qtips is as follows:

```
$(function () {
     $('[data-url]').each(function (i) {
         var element = $(this);
         element.qtip({
             content: {
                 text: "Loading...",
                 ajax: {
                     url: element.data('url')
                 }
             },
             position: {
                 viewport: $(window)
             }
         });
     });
});
```

Does anyone know why this is going wrong in `IE 9` and know of a workaround to this issue? Failing that, does anyone have experience with other `jQuery` tooltip plugins that work well with `Cufon` fonts and work reliably in all modern browsers?

Answer (score 2):

this was also happening to me and it was because i was including jQuery library twice.
needless to say removing one of the references fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't see how including the jQuery library twice could cause this unless they were two different versions of jQuery and you removed the one that caused the issue. Anyway. I worked around this as well but by loading the content from a div rather than using ajax. I made this change for performance reasons but it also resolved this problem for me. Thanks for sharing your experience with this issue.

Comment: I experienced the same and tracked it down to a jquery.ui file which was included twice.

Comment: Experienced the same, the jquery ui library was included twice.  Thanks!